# Can Blackberry Enterprise Server update its address list from Exchange on demand?

Tags: blackberry, bes

I need to setup an automated process to create mailboxes on Exchange 2010 and then corresponding Blackberry users on Blackberry Enterprise Server 5.0.3.

The problem is BES only gets an updated Global Address List form Exchange every 24 hours, so if I try to set up the Blackberry user straight after setting up the mailbox BES cannot find the user.

Is there anyway I can non-interactively force BES to get an update from Exchange everytime I create a new mailbox?